# jgraph like component on vaadin framework

Tags: java, graph, web-frameworks, vaadin

Currently I am working on a process manager kind application, which needs jgraph( http://www.jgraph.com ) kind of component. The process manager is a kind of process flow chart. I am currently using vaadin framework. Is there any such built in components available in vaadin or can i have any plugin to create a drag & drop graph for my app.

Please let me know if any one has already done this.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use jgraph with applet wrapper on vaadin

Answer (score 2):

You can use JUNG2 for that. A detailed explanation about how to do it can be found [here](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/346113#_19_message_335733).